# Focus Lost Inside Dropdown Filter Input In Prime React

Tags: reactjs, primereact

I have editable cells datatable . When I open dropdown for the first time as you can see like below it has focus on dropdown filter input.
[image]

After 1 or 2 seconds passed main dropdown Input took focus.                                                               [image]

My Dropdown is a cell in datatable. Which has filter option like people can filter by typing something in filter input field. But focus in filter input always lost to main dropdown input itself.My dropdown with cell editor returning like below

```
 <Dropdown
                    id="requsitionerDropDown"
                    virtualScrollerOptions={{ itemSize: 38 }}
                    appendTo={'self'}
                    value={options.value}
                    filter
                    autoFocus
                    style={{ width: '235%' }}
                    options={requisitonerList}
                    onChange={(e) => options.editorCallback(e.target.value)}
                    optionLabel="value"
                    optionValue="value"
                    className="w-full md:w-14rem"
                />
```

I tried to focus to my filter input by ref attribute but it always goes for main dropdown input like before. I tried to remove autofocus but didn't work.I tried to go with like below  and it focuses my input but it lost again to main dropdown input again. I think its a bug. How can I fix this issue ?

```
 useEffect(() => {
        let myInput = document.querySelector('div.p-dropdown-panel.p-component.p-connected-overlay-enter-done > div.p-dropdown-header > div > input');
        let reqDown = document.querySelector('#requsitionerDropDown');

        if (myInput != null) {
            if (reqDown != null) {
                reqDown.blur();
            }
            myInput.focus();
        }
    });
```

PrimeReact Version : 9.6.2 React Version : 18.2.0

Comment: could you please provide your code in codesandbox?

Answer (score 0):

Works fine for me: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-wdgtqh

I used the `filterInputAutoFocus` property as in the documentation.

https://primereact.org/dropdown/#api.Dropdown.props.filterInputAutoFocus

```xml
<Dropdown
        value={selectedCountry}
        onChange={(e) => setSelectedCountry(e.value)}
        options={countries}
        optionLabel="name"
        placeholder="Select a Country"
        filter
        autoFocus
        filterInputAutoFocus
        valueTemplate={selectedCountryTemplate}
        itemTemplate={countryOptionTemplate}
        className="w-full md:w-14rem"
      />
```

Comment: I was using react-idle-timer for project. That was causing to lost focus on input fields. I removed from project. And it works like expected.